# same code different outputs Selenium/Python/VSCODE

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, web-scraping

so I am trying to scrape a perfumes website and loop through filters to get hold of the perfumes(Since they only show 1000 perfumes each time and the site has 75,000+ perfumes). The thing is, sometimes it says the combination of filters gives us 30 perfumes while it is supposed to be zero or 1 or 2, definitely not 30. but when I run the code in another cell in a small scale it gives the right result. am i missing something ?

Here is the code cell with that gives faulty results:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import pandas as pd
import time


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")



driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(executable_path='C:/Users/armon/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)/chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
url = 'https://www.fragrantica.com/'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

perfumes_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeft"]/ul/li[5]/a')
perfumes_btn.click()

search_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a')))
search_btn.click()

time.sleep(3)

Industry_more = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[13]/div[2]/div/p/div/button'
Industry_dict = {'Industry_Fragrances' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Fragrances"]',
                'Industry_Cosmetics' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Cosmetics"]', 
                'Industry_Fashion' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Fashion"]', 
                'Industry_NaturalPerfumery': '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Natural Perfumery"]', 
                'Industry_Celebrity' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Celebrity"]', 
                'Industry_Accessories' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Accessories"]',
                'Industry_Jewelry': '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Jewelry"]', 
                'Industry_Retailer': '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Retailer"]',
                'Industry_Lingerie': '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Lingerie"]', 
                'Industry_NichePerfumes': '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Niche Perfumes"]'
            }


Gender_dict = {'Gender_Female' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="female"]',
                'Gender_Unisex' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="unisex"]',
                'Gender_Male' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="male"]'
            }


Country_more = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[10]/div[2]/div/p/div/button'
Country_dict = {'Country_USA' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="United States"]',
                'Country_France' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="France"]',
                'Country_Italy' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Italy"]',
                'Country_UK' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="United Kigdom"]',
                'Country_Brazil' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Brazil"]',
                'Country_UAE' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="United Arab Emirates"]',
                'Country_Russia': '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Russia"]',
                'Country_Spain' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Spain"]',
                'Country_Germany' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Germany"]',
                'Country_SaudiArabia' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Saudi Arabia"]',
                'Country_Sweden' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Sweden"]',
                'Country_Latvia' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Latvia"]',
                'Country_Poland' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Poland"]',
                'Country_Japan' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Japan"]',
                'Country_Netherlands' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Netherlands"]',
                'Country_Canada' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Canada"]',
                'Country_Australia' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Australia"]',
                'Country_Switzerland' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Switzerland"]',
                'Country_Argentina' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Argentina"]',
                'Country_Belgium' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Belgium"]',
                'Country_Pakistan' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Pakistan"]',
                'Country_Slovakia' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Slovakia"]',
                'Country_Austria' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Austria"]',
                'Country_Thailand' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Thailand"]',
                'Country_Philippines' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Philippines"]',
                'Country_SouthKorea' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="South Korea"]',
                'Country_Belarus' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Belarus"]',
                'Country_Israel' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Israel"]',
                'Country_Korea' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Korea"]',
                'Country_Greece' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Greece"]',
                'Country_Denmark' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Denmark"]',
                'Country_Norway' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Norway"]',
                'Country_Portugal' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Portugal"]',
                'Country_Iceland' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Iceland"]',
                'Country_Newzealand' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="New Zealand"]',
                'Country_Ukraine' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Ukraine"]',
                'Country_Romania' : '//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Romania"]'
                
            }


start_year_xpath = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/p/div/form/input[1]'
end_year_xpath = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/p/div/form/input[2]'

load_more_button = '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/button'
clear_filters_button = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/p/div/button'

industry_load = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Industry_more)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", industry_load)

country_load = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Country_more)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", country_load)




def start_scraping():

    elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="card-section")
    if len(elements) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(elements) < 60:
        return elements
    else:
        prev_count = len(elements)
        loading = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_button)))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loading)
        time.sleep(4)
        elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="card-section")
        now_count = len(elements)
        while now_count > prev_count:
            loading = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_button)))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loading)
            time.sleep(4)
            elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="card-section")
            prev_count = now_count
            now_count = len(elements)
    return elements
            



global df 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Link', 'Industry', 'Gender', 'Country', 'Year'])

def filter():
    for industry in Industry_dict.keys():
        for gender in Gender_dict.keys():
            for country in Country_dict.keys():
                for year in range(1920, 1930):

                    industry_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Industry_dict[industry])))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", industry_selected)
                    time.sleep(3)

                    gender_selected = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Gender_dict[gender])))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", gender_selected)
                    time.sleep(3)
                
                    try:
                        country_selected = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Country_dict[country])
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", country_selected)
                        time.sleep(3)
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        break
                         
                    start = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, start_year_xpath)))
                    start.clear()
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", start)
                    start.send_keys(year)

                    time.sleep(3)

                    end = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, end_year_xpath)))
                    end.clear()
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", end)
                    end.send_keys(year)

                    time.sleep(5) 

                    # start of new code

                    elements = start_scraping()   
                                     
                    home_pages = elements[1::2]
                    links = []
                    inc = 0
                    for link in home_pages:
                        link = home_pages[inc] # Getting the each div section
                        link = link.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value = "p")
                        link = link[0] # Selecting first paragraph (the one housing the link) element out of two
                        link = link.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value = "a")
                        link = link[0].get_attribute("href") # Extracting link from list
                        links.append(link)
                        inc +=1
                        
                    print("In year {} , We found {} perfumes.".format(year, len(links)))

                    if(len(links)> 0):
                        global df 
                        for link in links:
                            dict = {'Link' : [link], 'Industry' : [industry], 'Gender': [gender], 'Country': [country], 'Year': [year] }
                            dict_df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
                            df = pd.concat([df, dict_df], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

                        
                    # end of new code

                    clear  = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, clear_filters_button)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clear)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    


filter()
```

which gives me this:

```
In year 1920 , We found 0 perfumes.
In year 1921 , We found 2 perfumes.
In year 1922 , We found 1 perfumes.
In year 1923 , We found 2 perfumes.
In year 1924 , We found 0 perfumes.
In year 1925 , We found 2 perfumes.
In year 1926 , We found 30 perfumes.
In year 1927 , We found 30 perfumes.
In year 1928 , We found 30 perfumes.
```

when in fact year 1926 has zero perfumes.

and this is the small-scale and right code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import pandas as pd
import time


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")



driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(executable_path='C:/Users/armon/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)/chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
url = 'https://www.fragrantica.com/'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

perfumes_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="offCanvasLeft"]/ul/li[5]/a')
perfumes_btn.click()

search_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a')))
search_btn.click()

time.sleep(3)


industry = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="Fragrances"]' )))
gender = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="female"]' )))
country = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="ais-RefinementList-checkbox" and @value="United States"]' )))
start = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/p/div/form/input[1]')))
end = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="offCanvasLeftOverlap1"]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/p/div/form/input[2]')))
year = 1926



driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", industry)
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", gender)
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", country)
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", start)
start.clear()
start.send_keys(year)
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", end)
end.clear()
end.send_keys(year)
time.sleep(3)




def start_scraping():

    elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="card-section")
    if len(elements) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(elements) < 60:
        return elements
    else:
        prev_count = len(elements)
        loading = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_button)))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loading)
        time.sleep(4)
        elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="card-section")
        now_count = len(elements)
        while now_count > prev_count:
            loading = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_button)))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", loading)
            time.sleep(4)
            elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="card-section")
            prev_count = now_count
            now_count = len(elements)
        return elements
            


elements = start_scraping()

home_pages = elements[1::2]
links = []
inc = 0
for link in home_pages:
    link = home_pages[inc] # Getting the each div section
    link = link.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value = "p")
    link = link[0] # Selecting first paragraph (the one housing the link) element out of two
    link = link.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value = "a")
    link = link[0].get_attribute("href") # Extracting link from list
    links.append(link)
    inc +=1


print("In year {}, We have {} Perfumes.".format(year, len(links)))
```

and this is the output:

```
In year 1926, We have 0 Perfumes.
```

so what is it that I fail to see ? I already went through the code multiple times and idk what to change. sometimes it starts giving faulty results in later years but always around 1926 or 1927.. any tip is appreciated !

Comment: Hello, can you check the values you put in the variables (Industry_more, Industry_dict...) in the first code and (industry, gender...) in the second piece of code ? It might come from there.

Comment: I copy pasted them from the first cell .. also when the code is running , i checked and all is good..

Comment: @Armonia Do you have a specific reason to use Selenium, or are you fine with different scraping methods as well?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 Well I do need it to interact with the web and press on buttons and such, but I am open to other things as long as they get the job done.